# Arithmetic between double and integer in MIPS assembly

Tags: math, assembly, mips, mars-simulator

Below is a MIPS program that converts from Fahrenheit to Celsius. 
I've defined 3 variables, one of which is a `double` and the rest are all `integer`. In order to perform division or multiplication between the variables, however, I had to convert the `int` variables to `double` later in the code.

The whole reason I declared the variables as `int` not `float` or `double` is because I'm literally storing one-digit decimal constants, and I wouldn't need to use two registers for that, as`double` requires. However, now I realise I'm facing two new problems:

1) I now need to do two extra steps for each variable (moving to cp1 and converting to `double`)

2) After the line `mtc1.d $t1, $f6`, the values become `double` and they get stored in two registers like normal doubles instead of one register like integers, hence missing my intention completely.

My question is, which way is better for memory and program efficiency? Declaring the variables as all of the same data type and shortening the number of instructions but taking up more memory space than I need? 
Or giving the variables more suitable data types but costing myself 3 steps instead of just one?
Isn't there an efficient way to do arithmetic between two different data types in MIPS by using as few registers as possible?

```
.data
input: .double
cons1: .double 32
cons2: .word 5
cons3: .word 9

.text
#take double input from user
li $v0, 7
syscall             #value is stored in f0 (and f1 probably)


#subtract first constant
ldc1 $f2, cons1         #load the value 32 into f2 and f3
sub.d $f12, $f0, $f2        

#multiply by 5
lw $t1, cons2           #load 5 into t1     
mtc1.d $t1, $f4         #move the value in t1 to f4
cvt.d.w $f4, $f4        #convert value to single precision to be able to do 
                        #multiplication
mul.d $f12, $f12, $f4   

#divide by 9    
lw $t2, cons3           #load 9 into t2
mtc1.d $t2, $f6         #move the value in t2 to f5
cvt.d.w $f6, $f6        #convert value to single precision to be able to do 
                        #division
div.d $f12, $f12, $f6

#show result
li $v0, 3
syscall
```

Comment: For this type of program, you shouldn't worry about efficiency, but rather about expressing the problem in the clearest way possible. It's probably clearer to define the constants as doubles, in order to simplify the code.

Comment: Note also that the extra instructions needed to convert the constants may take as much memory space as would be needed to store the constants as doubles.

Comment: Why not use floats instead of doubles? The precision should be sufficient.

Comment: `div.d` is double-precision division.  `div.s` is MIPS single-precision division.  https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node20.html IDK why you think you have to convert to use `div`, or why you didn't use single-precision `float` the whole time.  (`float` division should be faster than `double`, though, on real hardware and probably in the simulator.)